# VBA Tengo problemas para llamar un rango que esta en otra hoja de mi libro

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Quería hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

Selection.FormulaR1C1 = Application.Goto(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("TRASLADOS").Range("RangePara"))

Lo que quiero es que la selección que tengo actualmente quede con los valores del rango dinámico que cree en la hoja  traslados llamado "RangePara".

El código completo seria:

```
Sheets("INVENTARIO").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
    Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(500, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = "PARA"

   ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(500, 0)).Select
     Selection.FormulaR1C1 = 
Application.Goto(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("TRASLADOS").Range("RangePara"))
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Que error estas recibiendo?

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido a SO en español.

Para llevar un valor de un rango a otro, vale con hacer algo en plan `RangoDestino.Value=RangoOrigen.Value`. Y el Select no es necesario. Así que tu código se quedaría en:

```
With Sheets("INVENTARIO")
    .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(500, 0).Value = "PARA"
    .Range(Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(6, 0), Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(506, 0)).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("TRASLADOS").Range("RangePara").Value
End With
```